# Using scanl function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a function that takes an int list and returns a sum using scanl

Below code works.

**Input: [1,2,3]**

```
sum_calc list = scanl (+) 0 [1..10]
```

**Output: [0,1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55]**

I want to edit it so that the output only goes up to the last element of the inputted list. I've tried using 0 [1..length list] but haskell spits this out at me.

Comment: Sorry, but what output do you want to get when run `sum_calc [1, 2, 3]`? Just `6`?

Comment: @SergeyKuz1001 I think OP wants `sum_calc [1, 2, 3] == [0, 1, 3]` (i.e. the cumulative sums of the list).

Comment: @SergeyKuz1001 so it should return [0, 1, 3, 6] .. so first is 0, and second is the first inputted value, third is the first and second inputted value added together, fourth would be that value added to the fourth element of the input. If that makes sense?

Comment: @pythonstudent98 I’d rather not write your code for you, but here’s a hint: your code is _almost_ there, but when you call `sum_calc` as it is currently written, it returns the cumulative sums of the list `[1..10]` rather than those of the input list `list`. How can you alter your code to use the input list?

Answer (score 1):

You can write this:

```hs
sum_calc = scanl (+) 0
```

So `sum_calc [1, 2, 3]` return `[0, 1, 3, 6]`.

You can also write

```hs
sum_calc list = scanl (+) 0 list
```

if you are confused by disappearance of `list`.

Comment: @pythonstudent98 What happens when you try it?

Comment: @pythonstudent98 That’s really weird — the presence or absence of `list` should have no effect whatsoever on how `sum_calc` works. What happens when you don’t include `list`?

Comment: @bradrn Probably the monomorphism restriction strikes.